# Transiting through Italy: Covid-19 restrictions

Tags: transit, covid-19, italy

Going to fly from Marseille to Tirana via Rome (Ciampino airport) in a month from now. Albania allows travelers to enter the country without PCR test / any kind of travel form. However, Italy requires proof of a negative test result and the completed EU PLF. Is this requirement enforced for those whose final destination is not Italy? Thank you.

Comment: Whether they require it today might well be different from whether they require it in a month. These things are changing fast now.

Comment: @Willeke You're right, but it would be nice to know where the relevant information is published now, so that a month later I can check the same source.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.